# The efficiency way of four nested loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested, multiprocessing

I have four nested loops in python.

```
data = {'alt' : talt,
        'lat' : tlat,
        'lon' : tlon,
        'LT'  : tpLT,
        'temp': temp}
        
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

gap_alt = 10.
int_alt = np.arange(30, 111, gap_alt)
lat_rng = np.arange(-55, 55.1, 10)
lon_rng = np.arange(0, 360.1, 30)

temp_all = np.full([len(lon_rng)-1, len(lat_rng)-1, len(int_alt), 24], np.nan)
```

Here, I have data (Dataframe) with altitudes, latitudes, longitudes, local times, and its temperatures.

The data is one-dimension (data), and I want to make this array to the four-dimensional array (temp_all).

```
for loop_lat in lat_grid:
    for loop_lon in lon_grid:
        for loop_ht in height_grid:
            for loop_hr in hour_grid:
                idx = [(data.lat >= lat_rng[loop_lat]) & (data.lat < lat_rng[loop_lat+1]) &
                (data.lon >= lon_rng[loop_lon]) & (data.lon < lon_rng[loop_lon + 1]) &
                (data.LT >= loop_hr) & (data.LT < loop_hr+1) &
                (data.alt >= int_alt[loop_ht]-gap_alt/2.) & (data.alt < int_alt[loop_ht]+gap_alt/2)][0]

                temp0[loop_lon, loop_lat, loop_ht, loop_hr] = np.mean(temp[idx])
```

In this process, it takes toooooo long time....
Is there any efficient way?

The efficiency way of four nested loops in Python

Comment: It looks like you already have some data set up. Could you describe the shape of that data and what it represents, as well as describing what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: A slightly faster way is to try and compute some of the items that you reuse in the outmost loop so that you don't keep recomputing it in the innermost loop, but looking at the general structure of the data and what you are trying to do would provide more efficiency gains.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I added the details of the data and what I want to do!

Comment: You can compute the index value for the outer loops in the outer loops, instead of forcing it to search the dataframe over and over and over.

Comment: @TimRoberts What does it mea? Could you please explain it more detail?

Answer (score 1):

What I mean by my comment is the following, moving the invariant parts of the expression out of the innermost loops.  This will probably be only a minor improvement in speed.  What you really need is a different approach, so you don't have to search through the `data` every single time.

```
for loop_lat in lat_grid:
    lats = (lat_rng[loop_lat] <= data.dat) & (data.lat < lat_rng[loop_lat+1])
    for loop_lon in lon_grid:
        lons = (lon_rng[loop_lon] <= data.lon) & (data.lon < lon_rng[loop_lon+1])
        for loop_ht in height_grid:
            hts =   (int_alt[loop_ht]-gap_alt/2 <= data.alt) & (data.alt < int_alt[loop_ht]+gap_alt/2)]
            for loop_hr in hour_grid:
                hrs = (loop_hr <= data.LT) & (data.LT < loop_hr+1)
                idx = lats & lons * hts & hrs
                temp0[loop_lon, loop_lat, loop_ht, loop_hr] = np.mean(temp[idx])
```